# Convert string column to decimal number within ABAP class SELECT

Tags: abap, opensql

in my SAP CRM table, ratings per lawyer are stored as strings, and I need to calculate an average per lawyer:

| ID_LAW | rating_LAW |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | '2.6' |
| 1 | '2.2' |
| 2 | '4.3' |

When writing the ABAP class, I am writing a SELECT statement, but I have not found a way to convert the string column to a decimal number within the SELECT so I can calculate the average rating right away

This is what I have so far:

```
class ZCL_LAWYER_RATINGS_TEST definition
  public
  final
  create public .

public section.
  TYPES: BEGIN OF t_lawyer,
    id TYPE c LENGTH 10,
    rating TYPE string,
  END OF t_lawyer,
  tt_lawyer TYPE TABLE OF t_lawyer.

  DATA: lawyers TYPE tt_lawyer.
protected section.
private section.
  METHODS: get_lawyers IMPORTING rating_threshold TYPE string.

ENDCLASS.

CLASS ZCL_LAWYER_RATINGS_TEST IMPLEMENTATION.

  METHOD get_lawyers.
    SELECT ID_LAW as rating, CONV #(rating_LAW) AS rating
    INTO TABLE @lawyers
    FROM LAWYERS_STAT
    WHERE rating >= @rating_threshold
    GROUP BY ID_LAW.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

The usage of CONV is giving me trouble: `CONV #(rating_LAW) AS rating`

Any suggestion how to achieve the conversion?

Answer (score 4):

ABAP SQL supports [`CAST`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abensql_cast_rules.htm) to convert values from columns of type `CHAR` or `SSTRING` into numeric types.

You need to provide the numbers as a valid number format e.g. quotes are invalid characters so you must remove them using [SQL string functions](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abensql_string_func.htm).

The possibilities depend on the ABAP version you use.

NB:

- It's forbidden to mix pure ABAP (`CONV`)and pure SQL (`rating_law`) all together, the database cannot understand what `CONV` means.
- Having `SELECT` inside or outside a class doesn't change anything.

Comment: If I'm using ABAP 7.40, can I use CAST in the SELECT list? `SELECT id_law, CAST( rating_law AS D16N ) AS rating INTO ...` 
I tried it, and got the error `Line 2: ")" is invalid here (due to grammar). contains an invalid character or`

Comment: Unfortunately, in 7.40, you can't do much ([CAST](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_740_index_htm/7.40/en-US/index.htm?file=abensql_cast.htm)). You need to find a workaround (SQL at database level, etc.)